# R and regexp: Extract name source from news

Tags: r

I have a scrap news by R like the following:

```
> View(mydf$title)
<name of the news> <dash> <source name>    
Матч КХЛ перенесен на 2 дня - Газета.Ru
Всероссийская универсиада 2010 - Interfax Russia
Звезда хоккея снялся в клипе популярного рэпера. ВИДЕО - Ura.ru
Трактор – Тролейбус 2:1 14.04.2011 – YouTube
```

I need to split `mydf$title` on the title news and name of source (- Газета.ru, - Interfax Russia, - Ura.ru, etc)
I try this `library(stringr)`:

```
mydf$sourse <- str_extract(mydf$title, '\\- [A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9." ]{0,}$')
mydf$sourse <- str_extract(mydf$title, "\\-[:space:[:alpha:][:punct:][:space:]]{0,}$")
mydf$sourse <- str_extract(mydf$title, '\\-\\s[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9[:punct:]\\s]{0,}')
mydf$sourse <- str_extract(mydf$title, "\\s-\\s[\\w+\\s.]{0,}$")
mydf$sourse <- str_extract(mydf$title, "\\s-\\s[:alpha:][:print:]$")
```

But does not work very well. How do I split a string optimally?
Thanks for the tips. Спасибо.

Note: `mydf` is data.frame:

```
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ title      : Factor w/ 100 levels...
 $ link       : Factor w/ 100 levels...
 $ guid.text  : Factor w/ 100 levels...
 $ guid..attrs: Factor w/ 1 level...
 $ pubDate    : Factor w/ 100 levels...
 $ description: Factor w/ 100 levels...
```

Comment: Could you clarify the structure of `mydf$title`? Is it a vector of `character`s? Or is it one long `character` that has newlines in it?

Comment: Take a look at str_split_fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try using `strsplit`, but I note that your separator is in fact two different types of dash:

```
strsplit(mydf$title, split=" [–-] ", useBytes=TRUE)
```

This will give you a list of elements. (As you can see, I couldn't get the encoding to be correct on my machine, but even so, it's clear that the news agency is always the last element of each list.  The only other issue that you will have to deal with then is that sometimes the source can also inlude a dash.  If this happens you will have to use paste to combine all but the last element of each list.

```
[[1]]
[1] "<U+041C><U+0430><U+0442><U+0447> <U+041A><U+0425><U+041B> <U+043F><U+0435><U+0440><U+0435><U+043D><U+0435><U+0441><U+0435><U+043D> <U+043D><U+0430> 2 <U+0434><U+043D><U+044F>"
[2] "<U+0413><U+0430><U+0437><U+0435><U+0442><U+0430>.Ru"                                                                                                                           

[[2]]
[1] "<U+0412><U+0441><U+0435><U+0440><U+043E><U+0441><U+0441><U+0438><U+0439><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+0443><U+043D><U+0438><U+0432><U+0435><U+0440><U+0441><U+0438><U+0430><U+0434><U+0430> 2010"
[2] "Interfax Russia"                                                                                                                                                                                       

[[3]]
[1] "<U+0417><U+0432><U+0435><U+0437><U+0434><U+0430> <U+0445><U+043E><U+043A><U+043A><U+0435><U+044F> <U+0441><U+043D><U+044F><U+043B><U+0441><U+044F> <U+0432> <U+043A><U+043B><U+0438><U+043F><U+0435> <U+043F><U+043E><U+043F><U+0443><U+043B><U+044F><U+0440><U+043D><U+043E><U+0433><U+043E> <U+0440><U+044D><U+043F><U+0435><U+0440><U+0430>. <U+0412><U+0418><U+0414><U+0415><U+041E>"
[2] "Ura.ru"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

[[4]]
[1] "<U+0422><U+0440><U+0430><U+043A><U+0442><U+043E><U+0440>"                               
[2] "<U+0422><U+0440><U+043E><U+043B><U+0435><U+0439><U+0431><U+0443><U+0441> 2:1 14.04.2011"
[3] "YouTube"
```

Comment: Failure: `Error in strsplit(mydf$title, split = "[–-]", useBytes = TRUE) : non-character argument`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are overcomplicating things:

```
strsplit(c("before - after", "123 - 456"), " - ", fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that comment.

Comment: Sorry, but my English is very "two-bit" - I am don't understand how use your code.

Comment: OK, tuned for your example: `strsplit(mydf$title, " - ", fixed=TRUE)`. The result should be a list. _For every row_ in `mydf`, it should hold a character vector of length 2 (provided that your `mydf$title` holds only items of the indicated format). The first item is the thing to the left of the dash, the second item is the thing to the right. If this (or @Andrie's solution) doesn't work, you should provide all your data, because then the problem is probably dependent on details of it.

Comment: Thanks for help, Nick. But I am could not use Andrie’s advice: `Error in strsplit(mydf$title, "-", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument`.
And else one thing – in stroke may be double dash (“Text text text – text text text – agency”).